# How can I import multiple .xlsx and .xls files into multiple tables in Access?

Tags: ms-access, import, excel, ms-access-365

I have 100 .xslx and .xls files with different formats and I need to import them all separately into Access keeping their original file names intact.

Folder example: 
C:\Users\username\Desktop\2019_data\foldername\

sample names  of the many different sheets in the folder=

LGPO221154-1-ANDERSON-CELL 18-49.xlsx
LGPO221154-1-ANDERSON-CELL 50_UP.xlsx
LGPO222975_1_CELL_49_UNDER_Bandera.XLS
LGPO222975_1_LL_49_UNDER_Comal.XLS

Comment: Will the data go into the same set of tables?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish after they all get loaded?

Comment: @MichaelKutz  The data will go into separate tables within one access database. I'm essentially going to import these into SQL and then merge them into one.

Comment: @AnthonyGenovese The data will go into separate tables within one access database. I'm essentially going to import these into SQL and then merge them into one.

Comment: Should be possible using a VBA or similar script.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done MSSQL in a while but if I remember you can do a ssis package.  I think its part of sql management studio. Where you can read in files and do inserts.